# Low Voltage Logic

Tags: voltage, digital-logic

I am having an issue where I have 8 logic lines where the "Voltage High" is only 1.9V. The device I am writing to requires at least 2.2V.

Is there a way to amplifier these signals. There are about 12 of them I need to boost?

Comment: Normal practise is to observe fan-in and fan-out factors for loading factors. Is this slew rate limited or current limited? Are these clocks? if so what freq? and which chips

Comment: 8 or 12 lines ? Is this due to different Supply voltages on an interface or loading or logic family differences?  If this is 2.7V logic for example 2.2 is max threshold for VinH and 1.5V max for VinL. What is the low margin like? enough for passive pullup?  ESR on VoutL is lower than VoutH so assymetric margins are possible.

Comment: Sorry 12 lines total

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two suggested options:

1. Logic Level Translation ICs: A search on DigiKey will point you to several parts designed to translate logic levels bidirectionally between two Vcc values.
2. Discrete BJTs or logic-level N channel MOSFETs, or arrays of these, if you need only unidirectional logic level translation: The lower level logic signals are applied to the base / gate, with the collector / Drain connected to the higher level Vcc. The logic signal will typically get inverted, though, which needs to be addressed in your code.

For 12 bit level translation, a 16-bit logic translation part would work, for instance, [SN74AVCH16T245](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74avch16t245.pdf) is a 16-bit **noninverting** bus transceiver using two separate configurable power-supply rails, supporting 1.2 Volts to 3.3 Volts on either side. Other examples: [74VCXH16245](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/74VCXH16245-D.PDF) and [54VCXH162244](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00041101.pdf).

Several semiconductor manufacturers also provide selection tools for identifying suitable translators, e.g. [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/logic/docs/translationresults.tsp?sectionId=458&voltageIn=1.8&searchDirection=1&voltageOut=3.3#voltintf).

Of course, there are many other ways to address this requirement, but the basic methodology is perhaps covered by the discussed options.

---

**Update:** As suggested by *clabacchio* in comments, a third option:

- If level translation is required solely from the lower to the higher voltage side (not bidirectional), cascaded inverter ICs can be used, with their supply pins tied to the higher side supply (Vcc). As long as the input of the inverter can recognize the 1.9 Volt input as high, the outputs will match the inputs, but at the higher logic voltage.
- If logic inversion is not an issue (i.e. it will be dealt with in code), a single set of inverters will do too.
- Inverters, and inverting Schmitt Triggers, are available in single, dual, quad, hex, octal and 16 channel packages, probably others as well. Using a Schmitt Trigger will reduce noise sensitivity on the input side.
- An IC like [74ls244](http://www.learn-c.com/74ls244.pdf) would just about serve for unidirectional buffering: High-level input voltage = 1.5 Volts, Low-level input voltage = 0.5 Volts at 2 Volts Vcc.
- For a more well-defined safe voltage range, the earlier bus transceiver suggestions still work better.

Comment: Also a simple buffer would do, although it may seem overkill

Comment: @clabacchio Could you share an example please? I can add it to my answer if you like. When I think of buffers, I'm thinking "*clock signal required, and latching delays*" as opposed to "*clock signal pass-through as just another signal*".

Comment: With buffer I mean two cascaded inverters, just to restore the logic level. If that's not a priority, a single inverter would suffice. If the high level is beyond the logic threshold with enough margin, it should work without too much static current.

Comment: Are using OP-Amps a solution at all?

Comment: @user1883691 (A) overkill, (B) complicated to set up the biasing etc (C) more expensive per bit

Comment: Thanks, for me, logic inversion won't work.  I only need to go unidirectional.  Can you recommend a PN for the cascade inverter IC?  Will the cascade inverter also amplify non-zero low levels (ie close to but not exactly 0)?

Comment: @user1883691 The part mentioned is not a cascade inverter, it is a cascade of two inverters, the first feeding into the next. So two of them for each *n* channels. Inverter ICs will not "amplify", they will simply switch to high when the input crosses their upper logic level threshold, and back to low when the input drops below their lower threshold.

Comment: those values are examples.. need exact design to determine optimal pullup to shift level.

Comment: @user1883691 Added an example of an octal buffer: Note the sensitivity of logic level thresholds to Vcc, from the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks: I think I am beginning to understand.  Take this guy: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT04.pdf. Its Vcc can be tied to 5v for example, but the VI can be anywhere 0 to VCC.  So if I send in i.e. 1.9V, I would get 0V from the first stage and 5 from the second stage?

Comment: @user1883691 Yes, that would work marginally as well: Note the variation of Vih and Vil agains Vcc, on the datasheet.